# W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment xxxxx not attached to a context

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I keep getting and IllegalStateException

```
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment RunScenarioFragment{8b6deff} (3523a253-d2c8-49f3-95ea-33bbbc0c308a)} not attached to a context.
```

on this line:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.green_check);
```

I have looked at other posts but am somewhat new to android studio and was having trouble adapting their solutions to my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS**

This does not happen every time. Only after I switch screens/fragments (bottom navigation) and click on the item which initiates this process. It takes place in an anonymous routine in the onCreate method of the fragment.

Comment: Where is "this line" executed? If it's called before system calls `onAttach` fragment will have no context.

Comment: See additional comments. Anonymous subroutine in the onCreate method of the fragment. It happens intermittently after changing fragments using bottom navigation.

Answer (score 1):

The *getResources()* method internally returns *requireActivity().getResources()* when called from a fragment.

*requireActivity()* throws IllegalStateException if not currently associated with an activity or if associated only with a context.

You mentioned that your code in called from *onCreate* method of the fragment. This method can be called while the fragment's activity is still in the process of being created.

Move the code snippet from *onCreate* method to *onCreateView* method if it has to do with instantiating the user interface; or you can  move it to *onActivityCreated*.

Comment: It is getting called in the onChanged event of an observer within the fragment, which is getting called from an onItemClicked event of a recycler view adapter being set in the onCreateView event of the fragment.